# Compose Multiplatform draw behind System bars in IOS

Tags: ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, compose-multiplatform

Cannot draw behind Top and Bottom Bars in IOS.

Hi,
I am trying KMP for android and ios but had a problem. In Kotlin [blog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2023/08/compose-multiplatform-1-5-0-release/) it says "Using the WindowInsets API, you can draw background content via Compose Multiplatform behind the notch" but I couldn't do it. Does anyone know how can I draw background for Top and Bottom Bar?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, disable platform-specific default insets being applied in the app.

- For **IOS** you need to disable safe area paddings being applied by the Switft UI by adding the following line in `iosApp/iosApp/ContentView.swift` file.

```swift
// iosApp/iosApp/ContentView.swift

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ComposeView()
                .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .all) // Add this line
                .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
    }
}
```

- For **Android** Make sure to call `enableEdgeToEdge()` in your Activity's `onCreate`.

```kotlin
// MainActivity.kt

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    enableEdgeToEdge() // Add this
    setContent {
        // composables
    }
}
```

Your app will now start drawing content behind the top and bottom bar; Now you can use WindowInsets API from Compose to apply correct padding from within compose.

```kotlin
@Composable
MyScreen() {
    Box(
        Modifier
            .background(Color.Red)
            .windowInsetsPadding(WindowInsets.safeDrawing)
    ) {
         // Content goes here
    }
}
```